# Error:(1, 0) android/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

My code was working fine in Android Studio version 2.3, i did update to new and latest version 3.0 and start getting the error on a working code  :

> Error:(1, 0) android/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder

This is the app level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.webapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Data Binding build error: \[data binding plugin\]: failed to setup data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862052/android-data-binding-build-error-data-binding-plugin-failed-to-setup-data-bi)

Comment: can we see the build.gradle file.?

Comment: @prdp89 check edit

Comment: @KapilRajput this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949494/7666442

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer as it works for me may it help others,Updating project level build gradle classpath from older to latest build gradle latest version i.e from `2.3.3 to 3.0.0` works for me and `DataBindingBuilder` error gets resolved

project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
 //   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' compiling code with older gradle version in updated/latest gradle version shows DataBindingBuilder error
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```